# how to draw line on a Map as per user's location(GPS) in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to draw a line on Map as per user's location changes (GPS Base), and i also want to measure distance user?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the part "i also want to measure distance".

Use "distanceFromLocation:" to measure the distance in meters, between two locations.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126-CH3-SW18

Comment: Patel Ashish is asking to draw a line on map.. why do you think its releated to "distanceFromLocation" ?